# Material-UI Typeography gutterbottom - Increase margin

Tags: material-ui

I'm running Material-UI v4 and the `Typography` elements when they have `gutterbottom` set all look to have way too little margin.

What is the correct way to global add more marginbottom to my Typography elements? I assume in the theme - but not sure how!

Answer (score 8):

## For MUI v5+

They changed the customization API to be component-centric so the other solutions won't work. [GH changelog](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/CHANGELOG.md#500-alpha8)

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTypography: {
      styleOverrides: {
        gutterBottom: {
          marginBottom: 16,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: This is accurate for overriding ALL gutterBottom. This will however not be nice if you would like a different gutterBottom on different components. If you want to only affect a specific component, you would do something like...

`MuiTypography: {styleOverrides: {h1: {'&.MuiTypography-gutterBottom': {marginBottom: defaultTheme.spacing(6.25),},},},}...`

Comment: This is not working for me with MUI v5.0.3 See my MRE on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/56371614-material-ui-typeography-gutterbottom-increase-margin-189zc?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 6):

You can override the value of `gutterBottom` with [theme `overrides`](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#global-theme-override):

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTypography: {
      gutterBottom: {
        marginBottom: 16,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

You can even base it on the global `spacing` value by separating out your "base/core" variables into their own theme, and building everything else upon it, i.e.:

```js
const baseTheme = createMuiTheme({
  spacing: 8,
});

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  ...baseTheme,
  overrides: {
    MuiTypography: {
      gutterBottom: {
        marginBottom: baseTheme.spacing(2), // 16px
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[designorant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4580739/designorant)'s answer is great if you want to adjust `gutterBottom` for all variants. However, if you would like to adjust the `gutterBottom` for each variant individually you can also use a [global css override](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#global-css-override):

```
const GlobalCss = withStyles({
    '@global': {
        '.MuiTypography-h1.MuiTypography-gutterBottom': {
            marginBottom: baseTheme.spacing(5)
        },
        '.MuiTypography-h2.MuiTypography-gutterBottom': {
            marginBottom: baseTheme.spacing(3)
        }
    }
})(() => null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution to override gutterBottom for an individual header in my theme.

```js
const overrides = {
  overrides: {
    MuiTypography: {
      h3: { 
             "&.MuiTypography-gutterBottom": { 
              marginBottom: "20px" 
          }
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Based on the [implementation][1] of the `Typography` component. `gutterBottom` is set to a fixed value of '0.35em'. It cannot be changed on the global theme. You'll have to wrap the typography component to apply custom margins.

See Github issue here for updates! Requested a feature for it.
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13371